# unexpected results when clearing a stream state using .clear()

Tags: c++, iostream

I'm trying to learn the ins and outs of working with data streams in c++, and I found some weird behaviour occurs when I try to use .clear() to reset a stream error state. To illustrate this, lets say I want to read data from a .txt file using ifstream:

```
int main() {

    ifstream fileStream("data.txt");

    double testDouble;
    string testString;

    fileStream >> testDouble;

    fileStream.clear();

    fileStream >> testString;
    cout << testString << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

data.txt only contains a single character, e.g. "b". This means, as expected, that fileStream gets set to a failure state when I attempt to read into testDouble, since the input from data.txt is not a double. The documentation tells me that this failure state will be reset when I call fileStream.clear(), which should then allow me to read the character from fileStream that caused the initial failure into testString and output the result in the terminal. Indeed, this is what happens, but only when data.txt contains the letter "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "o", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "y" or "z". All other letters result an empty testString and no output. If I don't put fileStream in a failure state first, I am able to read the data in data.txt with no problems. I am using Xcode 7.3 on OSX 10.11.3.

Comment: Is that really your code? Works as expected [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6481f49814cc0f8a).

Comment: Yes, I even just copypasted what I have written here to be sure. Same problem. Very strange.

Comment: I also just tried running the code you posted, and the exact same thing happens. Any character not in the list I previously stated results in an empty output... very odd EDIT I just tried running your code using Eclipse instead of Xcode, same thing happens

Comment: What return `fileStream.tellg()` with good and bad before and after reading `testString`? Bug looks like related to Mac OS X/clang/libc++ because of not reproducible with linux/clang/libstdc++

Comment: before reading testString:
tellg() = 1
good() = 1
bad() = 0
after reading testString:
tellg() = -1
good() = 0
bad() = 0

Comment: if this is indeed a bug related to the OS, is there a workaround that can achieve the same results?

Comment: I mean what return `tellg` in case when `testString` is empty before/after its reading, and in case when `testString` is not empty, not result of `istream::bad` and `istream::good`. If they really return different values, you can try use `seekg` as workound.

Comment: when 'testString' ends up empty,  'tellg' is 1 initially and -1 after reading
when 'testString' is successfully loaded, 'tellg' is 0 initially and -1 after reading. It seems like in the unsuccessful cases the stream is advancing when it shouldn't...